# Does the size of the image increases the game's size?

Tags: unity

I have an image which is about 2mb in size and I want to use it as a background for my app.My question is, will this image add 2mb to the game's size (like for example the game is 20mb and after adding the image it will be 22mb) or will it get reduced when I add it to my app?
I am using Unity by the way.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt No

Comment: Well, if you insert 2mb of information, what do you think will happen? The information has to be somewhere. You could try changing the image's format, maybe to something loosy if you don't need an exact copy.

Comment: @rlam12 the thing is, one of the apps I play has a background which is filled of drawings and stuff and it is only 30KB..Mine is simple but it is about 2mb..So why is that?

Comment: Maybe they use tiled bitmaps and what you see as a single image is just a collection of tiny images repeated where possible to decrease size. Or they are using JPEG instead of PNG or even a custom paletted image format

Comment: I believe you would have had the answer in like 2 minutes if you just tried it on your app

Comment: @fakeUser404 The app is not ready

Comment: Down voting for the clear lack of research. Common sense should answer this. Testing on a *blank app* should answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will, of course, add some data to the app. However the actual APK may not increase by exactly the size of that image. It may be compressed with other files to mean that its slightly smaller.

If you're worried about the size of images in your app, you should consider using vector images, images that are made of drawing instructions instead of raw pixel data (yes I know most image formats aren't very close to raw pixel data at all), this can mean thta many images can be much smaller file sizes, this however doesn't work for things like real world photographs, which can be larger file sizes than traditional images. Vector formats also have the advantages of scaling to fit many resolutions without looking terrible.