# High quality graphics but low apk size - How?

Tags: unity

So I have been playing this app that has so many high quality graphics with some 3d models and tons of levels and it is only 70mb in size.My app that has only 2 pictures is about 20 mb in size lol..Why?

Comment: You use Unity, they don't!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt clarify please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the size of the image increases the game's size?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134451/does-the-size-of-the-image-increases-the-games-size)

Comment: There may be several reasons for the difference in size. We don't know how they made their game, so we can't answer this question.

Comment: Some of the factors are the tech or middleware used (a full-featured engine will tend to create builds that are larger in filesize than something that uses only a handful of libraries), the size & number of assets used (some games achieve a high-quality look through judicious use of small or re-used assets, rather than splurge on content), compression applied, etc. Unity has some build profiling tools you can use to investigate which parts of your game are responsible for the largest contributions to build size, so that can be a useful starting point.

Comment: they may compress some data into smaller size , then decompress and load them when the game is in loading state

Comment: I'd like to add that an app will always have Unity libraries in it, so it can be about that size even if you didn't put any images in it.